# Is it necessary to include linker commands in CodeChecher?

Tags: linker, static-analysis

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72344910/6230282), I asked and received advice on invoking Clang Static Analyzer for doing cross-translation-unit analysis. But this is now a separate issue.

What I want to ask here, do I need to include linker commands when using the newer [CodeChecker](https://pypi.org/project/codechecker/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeChecker dev here. Linker information is not used during the analysis. You can read about the CTU mode in this user guide: https://github.com/Ericsson/codechecker/blob/master/docs/analyzer/user_guide.md#cross-translation-unit-ctu-analysis-mode

The workflow when using CTU mode is more or less the same, like without it. The standard workflow is to do a `CodeChecker log` then a `CodeChecker analyse` then a `CodeChecker parse` or `store` to view the results, just add the `--ctu` flag to the analysis command.